# Chi-squared distribution tail bound

Tags: probability, upper-lower-bounds, chi-squared

I have been studying about tail bounds and I read the following claim:

A variable $\xi \sim N(0, 1)$  satisfies the following tail bound for $t \geq 1$:

$ \mathbb{P}(\xi \geq t) \leq e^{-t^2/2} $

We also know that if $\mathbf{x} \sim N(0, \text{Id}_n)$ (where $\text{Id}_n$ is the identity matrix belonging in $\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$) the distribution of its squared Euclidean norm $\|\mathbf{x}\|^2$ is called $\chi^2$-distribution, that has the following tail bound for $t \geq 1$:
$ \mathbb{P}(\|\mathbf{x}\|^2 \geq t\cdot n) \leq e^{-t\cdot n/10}$

However somewhere else I have seen the following tail bound for the $\chi^2$-distribution:$ \mathbb{P}(\|\mathbf{x}\|^2 \geq t\cdot 2n) \leq e^{-t\cdot n/10}$

Which of two tail bounds for the $\chi^2$-distribution is correct and can we prove that using the Gaussian tail bound that I gave in the beginning?

Comment: So if I understand, you are concerned about getting the optimal constant in the bound ?

Comment: Yes. I want to verify the proof of a theorem afterwards that uses this bound.

Comment: Maybe this [blog post](https://ostrodmit.blog/2015/05/08/subexponential-random-variables/) that walks you through the steps of proving sub-exponentiality of the chi-square can help you ?

Comment: Thanks! I have a similar proof but I can't find the right constant. But anyway I found another approach to solve my problem :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One can verify the latter version of the bound using Lemma 1 from [[Laurent & Massart, 2000]](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.aos/1015957395), which states
that a $\chi^2(n)$ variable $Z$ satisfies

$$
\mathbb{P}(Z \geq n + 2\sqrt{nx} + 2x) \leq e^{-x}.
$$

We can write $2tn = n + (2t - 1)n$, so setting $x = tn/10$ we recover

$$
\mathbb{P}\left(\|x\|_2^2 \geq n + 2n\left(\sqrt{t/10} + t/10\right)\right) \leq
\exp(-tn/10).
$$

It suffices to show that $2t - 1 \geq 2 \left(\sqrt{t/10} + t/10
\right)$. Since $t \geq 1$, we can just show that
$2 t - 1 \geq 2 \cdot \frac{2t}{10} \geq 2 \left(\sqrt{t/10} + t/10\right)$, which is
true $\forall t \geq 1$ - the claim follows.